# SAAS - Custom domain for the same application

Tags: php, server, dns, saas

I have a SAAS in production and I want to give the customer the option of having a custom domain.

The application is in PHP without any javascript framework.

I would like to know the best ways to set up so that it is practical in terms of scale and implementation.

The operation should be as follows:

MAIN APPLICATION
myapp.com/company/product/clothes

The client will be able to navigate through the page through his domain as well, but everything being consumed from the main application without code duplication.

Customer domain example
companyapp.com/product/clothes

I currently use a shared hosting that contains WHM/CPANEL.

Comment: This isn't a PHP issue really. You need to register extra domain names and point them at your hosting account.

Comment: Então, como fazer essa configuração que é minha dúvida. xD

Comment: Sorry, this is an English-speaking site. Please translate your comment. If you prefer to communicate in Portuguese, please ask your question at https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: My mistake. So how to make this configuration that is my question.

Comment: Normally you do it through the hosting company, perhaps they have a form to complete in the control panel, or perhaps you need to speak to their support team. They have different systems. If you're unsure, speak to their helpdesk and/or read their documentation